# delegate member in NSMenu

Tags: cocoa, iboutlet, nsresponder

From  my understanding  the  delegating  class is the  one  which  always inherits from `NSResponder` class and `delegate` is only available  to  classes that  inherits from  `NSResponder`. `NSMenu` inherits directly from `NSObject`, so then why do i see `deletgate` in the  `outlets`?
Or is it that  i  misunderstood the options that you see after  ctrl-click on an object in Interface Builder?  I see `Outlets`,  `Referencing outlets`, `Received Actions` , what does these mean then?
I am  using Xcode 4  (10.7.3), if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you saw this but it's completely and totally incorrect. Delegation is just a pattern, there are no restrictions on the type of objects that can implement a delegate.

In fact, you are encouraged to use the delegation pattern in your own classes.

`NSMenu` declares its `delegate` property as an outlet in the header, which is why you see it in Interface Builder. You can do the same in your own code like so:

```
@interface YourObject : NSObject {}
@property (weak) IBOutlet id delegate;
@end
```

In Interface Builder, `Outlets` refers to the outlets that are defined in your class's header and that you can connect to other objects.  `Referencing Outlets` and `Referencing Actions` connections *from* other objects *to* your object.

Comment: Now going back to apples documentation i realized that i was wrong, i didnt read "often" word in it.



     `The delegating object is often a responder object—that is, an
     object inheriting from NSResponder in AppKit or UIResponder in 
     UIKit—that is responding to a user event. The delegate is an 
     object that is delegated control of the user interface for that 
     event, or is at least asked to interpret the event in an 
     application-specific manner.`